# DroidScript - почему не работают обработчики?

Tags: javascript, android

Решил попробовать, что такое [DroidScript](http://www.droidscript.org/).
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:

```
function b1_act(){
    app.ShowPopup('b1');
}
b3_={
    act:function(){
        app.ShowPopup('b3');
    }
}
function OnStart(){
    var buttons_layout = app.CreateLayout( "linear", "Vertical,FillXY" );

    var b1=app.CreateButton('b1');
    b1.SetOnTouch(b1_act);
    //Работает, но стоит немного усложнить, и..

    var b2=app.CreateButton('b2');
    b2.SetOnTouch(function(){
        app.ShowPopup('b2');
    });
    //или
    var b3=app.CreateButton('b3');
    b3.SetOnTouch(b3_.act); 
    //или
    /*
    =>
    ScriptError: Unexpected token ,, Line 1,
    */
    //или
    function b4_act(){
    //или var b4_act=function(){
        app.ShowPopup('b4');
    }
    var b4=app.CreateButton('b4');
    b4.SetOnTouch(b4_act); 
    /*
    =>
    ScriptError: b4_act is not defined, Line 1,
    */

    buttons_layout.AddChild(b1);
    buttons_layout.AddChild(b2);
    buttons_layout.AddChild(b3);
    buttons_layout.AddChild(b4);
    app.AddLayout(buttons_layout);
}
```

По-русски: почему обработчиком нельзя назначить

1. Анонимную функцию
2. Метод
3. Локальную функцию

?

**Для тех, кто пришел сюда за ответом:**

It is a limitation of DroidScript that you can only use global functions as control callbacks. 
It's because of the way DroidScript calls Java functions.
You can use your global object anywhere else except as a direct setting of the callback.

(с) Steve Garman

Comment: @Darth, наличие ответа не исключает необходимости сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: Блин,да что вам всем не ясно то в моем вопросе? Или этот вопрос тоже надо сформулировать получше?

Comment: Если вы не можете понять, в чем вопрос - это не обязательно значит, что вопрос плох. Точно так же - если вы не нашли сам вопрос, это не значит что его нет. Подсказываю - посмотрите в заголовке. Также специально для вас перевел с javascript на русский, под куском кода. Можете еще ответы почитать, может это наведет вас на мысль,в чем было дело. Если всё это не поможет вам понять суть вопроса - просто поверьте, что могут найтись люди, у которых возникнет тот же вопрос. Постарайтесь представить такую ситуацию, пожалуйста. Я понимаю, вам трудно понять, о чем речь, но я старался как мог.

Comment: Вы, наверное, не **никто**, и наверняка не **все**. Я вообще не понимаю, что вы тут делаете. Не ясен вопрос - найдите себе попроще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ от разработчика DroidScript:

DroidScript makes use of the JavaScript->Java bridge in Android which only supports the passing of primitive types between the two domains, so that is the reason we do not support anonymous functions by default.  We could use a work-a-round by creating id maps of function objects, but decided that this will only encourage the use of anonymous functions and take DroidScript out of the reach and understanding of newbie coders.

I hope that makes some sense :)

Regards

David